# UITableView was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it in ViewPagerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have one viewPagerController
Inside that, I have Tableview..

But when i swipe to other page , It crashed having the following error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'An instance 0x7fb99b1aa800 of class UITableView was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it.

I have tried removing delegate on viewWillDisappear but not worked for me..

Anyone can help?

Comment: remove all observe on `viewDidDisappear` and register it again on `viewDidAppear`

Comment: @Tj3n, can you show code for that?

Comment: can you show your code? it seems that you are observing something and when it fires your listener (tableView) was already deallocated

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove observer immediately after changes in value for which u have put observer 
...E.g if you put observer on dictioanry for track old and new value of dict then after value change immediatley remove observer and then you may resolve that issue.

or

comment all observer and tell me problem is resolved or not ?
Thanks